# consuming wcf from testing machine of sharepoint

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint

BACKGROUND:

I have a WCF which is working great on my dev, him and his client.
I deployed it on the testings servers.

The testing is built with 3 layers, content, publish and web. content is where I put all my content into the Sharepoint, and it can be accessed only from the VPN and it's http, meaning that if I want to go from my dev machine to the website of the testing-content I put in explorer `http://testing`.

The publish is something middle, I never touch it, and the data moves from the content to the other 2.

The web is the one open to the public, is https and has a load balancer, and you can test my WCF with this url https://testnew.mizrahi-tefahot.co.il/_vti_bin/skywcf/skyservice.svc

PROBLEM:

In my dev I consume my dev WCF perfectly. also the MEX is working great both from the testing-content and the testing-web as you can see for yourself in the link above, same is the wsdl.

While trying to create a client to consume the testing-web service I get this error message 
(while trying to do "add service reference"):

> There was an error downloading
>   'https://testnew.mizrahi-tefahot.co.il/_vti_bin/skywcf/skyservice.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request. Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'https://testnew.mizrahi-tefahot.co.il/_vti_bin/skywcf/skyservice.svc'.
>   Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by
>   service
>   https://testnew.mizrahi-tefahot.co.il/_vti_bin/skywcf/skyservice.svc. 
>   The client and service bindings may be mismatched. The remote server
>   returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the
>   content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the
>   expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.. If the service is defined in
>   the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service
>   reference again.

while trying to consume the testing-content service in my dev machine it creates the service reference but when trying to call methods i get the html of the web page that you get when you try to go to the service via browser. looking at fiddler i see he gives me the "Object moved to here" message adding some kind of token to the url (this is the html):

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body> <h2>Object moved to <a href="%2f_vti_bin%2fSkyWCF%2f(X(1)S(5hwwif450myurs45h5ihnn55))%2fSkyService.svc%3fAspxAutoDetectCookieSupport%3d1">here</a>.</h2> </body></html>
```

any help?

EDIT:web configs

server

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Sharepoint.BankMizrahi.Sky.WCF.ServiceBehavior" name="Sharepoint.BankMizrahi.Sky.WCF.SkyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Sharepoint.BankMizrahi.Sky.WCF.ISkyService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Sharepoint.BankMizrahi.Sky.WCF.ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://mizrahi"/>
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="siteUrl" value="http://mizrahiadmin/sky" />
    <add key="LogName" value="SkyService" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

client

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISkyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_ISkyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://mizrahidev/_vti_bin/SkyWCF/SkyService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISkyService"
                contract="ServiceReference1.ISkyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISkyService" />
            <endpoint address="http://mizrahi/_vti_bin/SkyWCF/SkyService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_ISkyService"
                contract="ServiceReferenceForTesting.ISkyService" name="CustomBinding_ISkyService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post bindings from this WCF web.config (or is it built using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory)? As well as client binding configuration? Maybe you have wrong binding definition (<security mode="TransportWithCredentials"> instead of <security mode="Transport">)

Comment: added configs of server and client

Comment: maybe changing httpGetEnabled="true" to httpsGetEnabled="true" will do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, seems that the answer was that the server was sessionStateEnabled and therefor tried to use cookies and the solution was simply to disable the cookies

```
<system.web>
<sessionState mode="Off"/>
```

thats for the testing-content, about the testing-web it seems i need to find a way to pass the load balanced that is stripping the https